# replace the alphanumeric numbers with X

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace the alphanumeric text with X for numbers but my text also has got other numbers which are not alphanumeric and those not to be replaced. I could able to locate the alphanumeric using the code below but unable to replace them.

Code

```py
result = re.sub(r'\S*\d+\S*,'',text)
```

```py
text = my text contains of the 33109 following values RT3123SO55 and also with certain numbers godwil_5708 and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453
```

expected output is

```py
my text contains of the 33109 following values RTXXXXSOXX and also with certain numbers godwil_XXXX and XXXstwe and XyXycX 456453
```

Comment: You should count yourself lucky to have received so many quality answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could try to use PyPi's regex library instead:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\d
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XfK4gX/1)

---

- `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b` - First match what we don't want. In this case I matched any 1+ digits with optional decimals inbetween word-boundaries;
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - Forget what we matched and exclude it from the final results;
- `|` - Or;
- `\d` - Any single digit.

---

```
import regex as re
s = 'my text contains of the 33109 following values RT3123SO55 and also with certain numbers godwil_5708 and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453'
print(re.sub(r'\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\d', '*', s))
```

Prints:

```
my text contains of the 33109 following values RT****SO** and also with certain numbers godwil_**** and ***stwe and *y*yc* 456453
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `re` is to match a word that has at least a digit and a char a-zA-Z and then replace the digits from the match with X

```
(?i)\b(?=[^\W\d]*\d)[\d_]*[A-Z]\w*
```

- `(?i)` Inline modifier for case insensitive (you can also use `re.I` on re.sub)
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?=[^\W\d]*\d)` Positive lookhead to assert at least a digit ( `[^\W\d]` is a word char without a digit )
- `[\d_]*[A-Z]` Match optional digits or `_` and then match A-Z
- `\w*` Match optional word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9ek3w/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?i)\b(?=[^\W\d]*\d)[\d_]*[A-Z]\w*"
text = "my text contains of the 33109 following values RT3123SO55 and also with certain numbers godwil_5708 and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453"

print(re.sub(pattern, lambda m: re.sub(r"\d", "X", m.group()), text))
```

Output

```
my text contains of the 33109 following values RTXXXXSOXX and also with certain numbers godwil_XXXX and XXXstwe and XyXycX 456453
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a way to do this purely with RE. However, here's a composite approach that seems to fulfil the brief:

```
import re
text = "my text contains of the 33109 following values RT3123SO55 and also with certain numbers godwil_5708 and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453"

def replace_numbers(s):
    tokens = s.split()
    for i, t in enumerate(tokens):
        if not t.isdigit():
            tokens[i] = re.sub(r'\d', 'X', t)

    return ' '.join(tokens)

print(replace_numbers(text))
```

**Output:**

```
my text contains of the 33109 following values RTXXXXSOXX and also with certain numbers godwil_XXXX and XXXstwe and XyXycX 456453
```

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try:

```
import re

text = 'my text contains of the 33109 following values RT3123SO55 and also with certain numbers godwil_5708 and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453'

s = re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Za-z_])\d+|\d+(?=[A-Za-z_])', lambda x: 'X' * len(x.group(0)), text)
print(s)
```

Result:

```
my text contains of the 33109 following values RTXXXXSOXX and also with certain numbers godwil_XXXX and XXXstwe and XyXycX 456453
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
import re
```

```
pattern = r"\b\d+\b|(\d)"
```

```
s = "my text contains of the 33109 following values RT3123SO55 and also with certain numbers godwil_5708 and 323stwe and 8y9yc2 456453"
```

```
print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: 'X' if x.group(1) else x.group(), s))
```

displays

```
my text contains of the 33109 following values RTXXXXSOXX and also with certain numbers godwil_XXXX and XXXstwe and XyXycX 456453
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nak0lP/1) <sub>¯\*(ツ)*/¯</sub>  [Code demo](https://ideone.com/A6mbzz)

If there is match of a string of digits delimited by word boundaries (`\b\d+\b`) nothing will be captured so the lambda's `if` clause evaluates `false` and the match is returned (leaving that part of the string unchanged); else if a single digit is matched *and* captured (`(\d)`), `'X'` is returned.

Note that the order of the alternation is important: `r"(\d)|\b\d+\b"` will not work.

Comment: Special thanks to @Thefourthbird who assisted me in the formulation of the  lambda clause. I had initially written the statement in Ruby but, being only vaguely familiar with Python, I got to `re.sub(pattern, lambda ???, s)` before reaching my Python limitations. I therefore asked bird #4 if he could translate the Ruby block, `{ |s| $1.nil? ? s : 'X' }` to a Python lambda, which he did. If fact, he gave me the "Code demo" link.